# Is there a way to create a new column based on a substring and text that follow it?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, filtering

I am working with triqler data outputs. I have been able to convert it into a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Jan05 GN=XYZ NA | Q9GLD3;A0A0A0RBT6 |
| Dec25 GN=ZYX Y | A0A8I3PIE0;A0A8I3PEP4;A0A0B4J198 |
| Nov12 GN=NHAN Y | P60524;A0A1K0GGH0;A0A8I3P9B9 |
| May22 GN=GZV X | P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7 |
| Jun24 MNIAV X | P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7 |
| May22 CAUCGZV Y | P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7 |

I need to create a new column that either uses the string after the "GN=" from the values in column A or the first part before the semicolon in column B if there is no "GN=" in column A.

In other words, I need it to look like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan05 GN=XYZ NA | Q9GLD3;A0A0A0RBT6 | XYZ |
| Dec25 GN=ZYX Y | A0A8I3PIE0;A0A8I3PEP4;A0A0B4J198 | ZYX |
| Nov12 GN=NHAN Y | P60524;A0A1K0GGH0;A0A8I3P9B9 | NHAN |
| May22 GN=GZV X | P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7 | GZV |
| Jun24 MNIAV X | P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7 | P09582 |
| May22 CAUCGZV Y | P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7 | P09582 |

I am not sure which packages or commands I should be using to accomplish this goal. I think that a conditional statement would be the way to go.

Comment: can you add the code you use it? or tried to ?

Comment: so we can reproducible data to test on it with you?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```py
df['C'] = (df['A'].str.extract('GN=([^\s]+)')[0]
           .fillna(df['B'].str.split(';').str[0]))
```

```
print(df)

                 A                                 B       C
0  Jan05 GN=XYZ NA                 Q9GLD3;A0A0A0RBT6     XYZ
1   Dec25 GN=ZYX Y  A0A8I3PIE0;A0A8I3PEP4;A0A0B4J198     ZYX
2  Nov12 GN=NHAN Y      P60524;A0A1K0GGH0;A0A8I3P9B9    NHAN
3   May22 GN=GZV X      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7     GZV
4    Jun24 MNIAV X      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7  P09582
5  May22 CAUCGZV Y      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7  P09582
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
data['new_column']=data.apply(lambda x:x["A"].split("GN=")[1] if("GN="in x["A"]) else x["B"].split(";")[0],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on the previous answer to eliminate NA

```
import pandas as pd
#example of data
cols=['A','B']
data=[['Jan05 GN=XYZ NA', 'Q9GLD3;A0A0A0RBT6'],['Jan05 GN=XYZ NA','Q9GLD3;A0A0A0RBT6'],['Jun24 MNIAV X','P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7']]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
df
df['C']=df.apply(lambda x:x["A"].split("GN=")[1].split()[0] if("GN="in x["A"]) else x["B"].split(";")[0],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
action1 = df['A'].str.split('GN=',expand=True)[1].str.split(' ',expand=True)[0]
action2 = df['B'].str.split(';',expand=True)[0]
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].str.contains('GN='),action1, action2)
df
###
                 A                                 B       C
0  Jan05 GN=XYZ NA                 Q9GLD3;A0A0A0RBT6     XYZ
1   Dec25 GN=ZYX Y  A0A8I3PIE0;A0A8I3PEP4;A0A0B4J198     ZYX
2  Nov12 GN=NHAN Y      P60524;A0A1K0GGH0;A0A8I3P9B9    NHAN
3   May22 GN=GZV X      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7     GZV
4    Jun24 MNIAV X      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7  P09582
5  May22 CAUCGZV Y      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7  P09582
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['C'] = (
    df['A'].str.extract('GN=(.+) ')
    .where(df['A'].str.contains('GN='),df['B'].str.extract('^(.+?);.*'))
)

print(df)
```

**Result**

```
                 A                                 B       C
0  Jan05 GN=XYZ NA                 Q9GLD3;A0A0A0RBT6     XYZ
1   Dec25 GN=ZYX Y  A0A8I3PIE0;A0A8I3PEP4;A0A0B4J198     ZYX
2  Nov12 GN=NHAN Y      P60524;A0A1K0GGH0;A0A8I3P9B9    NHAN
3   May22 GN=GZV X      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7     GZV
4    Jun24 MNIAV X      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7  P09582
5  May22 CAUCGZV Y      P09582;A0A1R3UGQ4;A0A8I3NWV7  P09582
```